# Meaning of 閉店ガラガラガラ in the following sentence

Tags: meaning, manga, dialects, kansai-ben, sports

An American boxer has been living in Japan for 3 years. He lives in the Kansai area, so he speaks Kansai dialect. He complains that after 3 years in Japan he still hasn't fought against a really strong opponent, then he says this sentence:

> ちゃんと強いヒトホンマ相手頼んますわ〰　ほな前座はこれにて―――　閉店ガラガラガラ――

[Here you can see the whole page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0E48.jpg). What is the meaning of the second part of the sentence, in particular 閉店ガラガラガラ? Is that Kansai-ben too? Thank you for your help!

Comment: 漫才コンビ「ますだおかだ」の岡田圭右さんのギャグですよね・・・『リクドウ』って、割と新しい漫画でしょう？

Comment: @Chocolate そう、２０１４年－連載中です。

Comment: 「閉店ガラガラガラ」が岡田圭右さんのギャグであることも、上下に開閉するシャッターの音であることも全く知らずに回答しました。シャッター音も確かに「ガラガラガラ」ですが、左右に動く「引き戸」の音も岡田さんとは関係なしに、また関西弁とも関係なしに、日本語で「ガラガラガラ」と表現します。「ガラガラガラ」は「引き戸」を開け閉めするときの擬音語として普通に使われます。しかし、日本では引き戸は今ではほとんど使われなくなりました。

Answer (score 8, accepted):

「ほな前座はこれにて」 → "Well then, that's it for the opening act."

「閉店ガラガラ」 is one of the signature shticks of the comedian [岡田圭右](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%B2%A1%E7%94%B0%E5%9C%AD%E5%8F%B3), of the Kansai comedy duo ますだおかだ, typically used at the end of their comedy sessions. (「閉店」 means the closing of a shop and 「ガラガラ」 is here an onomatopoeia for the shutter being pulled down.)　The extra 「ガラ」 in the manga could be a precaution against a potential lawsuit.

Comment: Oh, so it's not the boxer who is talking here right?

Comment: No, it's supposed to be the boxer. Maybe I should have given "Well then, that's it for **my** opening act." for that line.

Comment: I thought it could be the presenter talking. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 3):

ガラガラガラ is an onomatopeia representing the RATTLE NOISE of opening or closing a sliding door. In the given phrase, the noise means closing the door for "閉店 lit. *closing a store/shop for the day*".